# Execute a sql script inside visual studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a script generated by ado.net entity model after changing the database. i need to execute this script inside visual studio 2012. 
This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yea4bc1b.aspx) was not of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used schema compare tool for VS 2012. This not only created a script for me but also updated the production database to exact copy of development database.
Here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted concerns database project scripts, not running ad-hoc queries.

To run an ad-hoq query, you can [add a connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0wbea1ae(v=vs.110).aspx) to the database in Server Explorer, then select "New Query" from the database's context menu.

You can also use [SQL Server Object Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272693%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to add a connection to a specific server, view all databases and execute ad-hoc queries. This is a more powerful feature, almost as powerful as using SSMS itself.

Comment: Did you try to run it? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is a link rot on the "add a connection" hyperlink.